# How to set the group in DALI system on the bus?

Tags: dali

When I have 6 gears on the DALI bus, how to set up a pair of two to the group by command?or another way to set?

thanks!

Comment: Here is the command [list](http://www.rayzig.com/manual/rayzig.html?DALIcommands.html). Commands 96-111 are used to "add to a group"! Can you be more specific about your problem!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command 96 Add To Group 0, for example. This would need to be sent twice within 75ms because it is a configuration command, and you would probably want to send it using short addressing, so you need to repeat this for each short addressed gear that you want to add to the group. Example

```
Command 96 Add To Group 0, sent to short address 3 (0x0760)
Command 96 Add To Group 0, sent to short address 3 (0x0760)

Command 96 Add To Group 0, sent to short address 4 (0x0960)
Command 96 Add To Group 0, sent to short address 4 (0x0960)
```

If you haven't got unique short addresses set up yet on your bus, you could disconnect the other 4 gears or remove power from them, and then you can send the Command 96 using broadcast mode.

```
Command 96 Add To Group 0, sent broadcast (0xFF60)
Command 96 Add To Group 0, sent broadcast (0xFF60)
```

Comment: Where can I find out if it is a configuration command?

Comment: @張簡麒耀 In the standard, currently [IEC62386-102:2014 Ed 2](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/6955). Section 11 Definition of Commands, Table 15 has a Send Twice column with tick marks for the commands which need to be sent twice. In the previous [Ed 1](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/20477), section 11.2.1 General Configuration Commands, said commands 32-129 need to be sent twice. The DALI tag on this website mentions the name of the standard, so even if you haven't come across it from a general web search, it should be clear to users of this site that IEC62386 defines DALI technically.